# Адекватное регулярное выражение для поиска номеров телефонов СНГ

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

нужно **рабочее** регулярное выражение на python для поиска номеров телефонов СНГ.
для телефонов нашел такое регулярное выражение:

```
r'(\+7|8|7).*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{2}).*?(\d{2})'
```

но она собирает не только телефоны, но и всякий мусор вроде `83423`
есть у кого более совершенное решение, чтобы собирала телефоны в форматах например `+7 911 912 92 92` или `79119129292` или `8911912 92 92` итп, но отсеивала просто наборы цифр вроде `8974353` или `7942657658794532453` итп?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос минимально рабочий код, так больше шансов что кто-нибудь ответит.

Comment: @DGDays в вопросе достаточно информации.

Comment: как на счёт других [восьми стран членов СНГ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2#%D0%A7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%93)? ;)

Comment: https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#phone-numbers Вот так и получаем идиотские сайты в рунете типа *для всех*, а по факту...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ориентируясь на тесты, которые вы приложили, это должно подойти:

`pattern = \b\+?[7,8](\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2})\b`

я выделил первой группой только сам номер, если нужно достать *full match*, то пишите `.group()`