# Как отфильтровать все номера в тексте?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas

Есть такая таблица:

```
                                              Unnamed: 5
2550               +380639231808, Зеркло Мария Орестовна
2551               раролджєжопа, Кролик Вера Герасимовна
2552           063-070-99-48, Марийчук Надежда Иосифовна
2553           063 076 66 68, Марийчук Надежда Иосифовна
2554    (097)5455793 Слуцький Т., Надежны Тарас Олегович
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы записать в список только номера в формате 0999999999. Я так понимаю, что это делается через регулярные выражения, но я смог только вывести все цифры.

Мой код такой:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    line_number = 2550 + i
    line_content = str(sheet_1.iloc[[line_number], [5]])
    res = re.sub('[^\d]', '', line_content)
    print(res)
```

В итоге нужно получить список, где все номера в едином формате:

```
phones = ['0639231808', '0630709948', '0630766668', '0975455793']
```

Comment: А вам не подойдёт удаление всех нецифровых символов? `sheet_1['phone_numbers'] = sheet_1['content'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')`?

Comment: таблица - это DataFrame?

Comment: @MaxU да, DataFrame

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew помимо номеров в строке есть еще мусор из цифр, так что не вариант

Comment: @MaxU дополнил вопрос результатом, который хотел бы получить

Comment: Почему для пяти исходных записей четыре на выходе и во всех четырех одинаковый номер??

Comment: Попробуйте `df['имя_столбца'].str.extract(r'\b(\d(?:\D?\d){9,})\b', expand=False).str.replace(r'\D+','')`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Адекватное регулярное выражение для поиска номеров телефонов СНГ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082870/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%9d%d0%93)

Comment: Я не уверен, что это дубликат, см. [тест регулярного выражения из того вопроса](https://regex101.com/r/xyNkGC/1). Уверен на все 100%, если [моя догадка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220289/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5#comment2135180_1220289) верна. @EduardKumskyi Мой код помог решить задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = """                                              Unnamed: 5
2550               +380639231808, Зеркло Мария Орестовна
2551               раролджєжопа, Кролик Вера Герасимовна
2552           063-070-99-48, Марийчук Надежда Иосифовна
2553           063 076 66 68, Марийчук Надежда Иосифовна
2554    (097)5455793 Слуцький Т., Надежны Тарас Олегович"""

tel = []
rr = r"(\d{10,})|(\d+\){1}\d+)|(([ -]{1}\d{2,3}[ -]{1}\d{2,3}){2})"
res = re.findall(rr, txt)
for gr in res:
    for st in gr:
        if len(st) >= 10:
            st = re.sub('[^\d]', '', st)
            if len(st) > 10:
                st = st[-10:len(st):]
            tel.append(st)
print(tel)
```

> ['0639231808', '0630709948', '0630766668', '0975455793']

Может слегка громоздко, зато работает.